# Can I refactor my code anymore?

Tags: c#, linq, selenium

I have written one method; however I feel I can refactor it even more but not sure what

Can someone help me here?

```
    public static PaymentOptions GetPaymentOptions_NonGBCulture(TestConfigurationCDO testConfiguration, int siteId)
    {
        var paymentOptions = default(PaymentOptions);

        var paymentOptionList = SitePaymentRepository.GetSitePaymentInfoBySiteId(
        testConfiguration,
        siteId);

        var paymentAuto = paymentOptionList.First(x => x.PaymentType == PaymentMethod.PayPalDirect || x.PaymentType == PaymentMethod.Braintree || x.PaymentType == PaymentMethod.BankTransfer || x.PaymentType == PaymentMethod.AdyenDropIn);

        paymentOptions = new ClientCheckoutOptions()
        {
            paymentMethod = paymentAuto.PaymentType
        };

        return paymentOptions;
    }
```

I feel if I create list for possible Payment Type as below

```
     PaymentMethod[] checkoutGroup = { PaymentMethod.PayPalDirect, PaymentMethod.Braintree, PaymentMethod.BankTransfer, PaymentMethod.AdyenDropIn };
```

But not sure how do I add that check in query

Comment: `.First(x => checkoutGroup.Contains(x.PaymentType));`

Comment: Thank you!! @PeterCsala - Do you think I have any more room for improvement in this method?

Comment: You can also get rid of the `paymentOptions` variable. So, your return could be streamlined like this: `return new ClientCheckoutOptions { paymentMethod = paymentAuto.PaymentType };`

Comment: Ohh yes..thanks a lot!!!!

Comment: I am not able to vote your answer @PeterCsala

Comment: I've left a post please check that.

Comment: The primary point of the Code Review Community is to review code that is working as expected and provide suggestions on how that code can be improved. This seems to be a `How to` question and that would be better on the stackoverflow site rather than on the Code Review site. `How to` questions generally indicate the code in the question is not working as expected.

Comment: On top of that, there is no description of what your code is supposed to be doing. Peter wrote a surprisingly good answer considering you gave them little to work with, but please, next time, take a look at [what makes a good question](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6429/52915).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see at least two places where you can make your code more concise.

### `PaymentType`

As you have suspected replacing multiple `x.PaymentType == PaymentMethod.XYZ ||` statements with a collection lookup might help. With this approach you separate data from operation.

#### Before

```cs
var paymentAuto = paymentOptionList
   .First(x => x.PaymentType == PaymentMethod.PayPalDirect 
       || x.PaymentType == PaymentMethod.Braintree 
       || x.PaymentType == PaymentMethod.BankTransfer 
       || x.PaymentType == PaymentMethod.AdyenDropIn);
```

#### After

```cs
ImmutableArray<PaymentMethod> checkoutGroup = new []
{ 
   PaymentMethod.PayPalDirect, 
   PaymentMethod.Braintree,
   PaymentMethod.BankTransfer,
   PaymentMethod.AdyenDropIn 
}.ToImmutableArray();

var paymentAuto = paymentOptionList
   .First(x => checkoutGroup.Contains(x.PaymentType));
```

Note: I've used here Immutable collection to prevent accidental (or intentional) add and/or remove.

### `paymentOptions`

You can get rid of this variable because you have set it once (the initialization code is unnecessary) and immediately return.

#### Before

```cs
public static PaymentOptions GetPaymentOptions_NonGBCulture(TestConfigurationCDO testConfiguration, int siteId)
{
    var paymentOptions = default(PaymentOptions);

    //...

    paymentOptions = new ClientCheckoutOptions()
    {
        paymentMethod = paymentAuto.PaymentType
    };

    return paymentOptions;
}
```

#### After

```cs
public static PaymentOptions GetPaymentOptions_NonGBCulture(TestConfigurationCDO testConfiguration, int siteId)
{
    //...

    return new ClientCheckoutOptions { paymentMethod = paymentAuto.PaymentType };
}
```

Note: In case of object initialization you don't need to explicitly call the parameterless ctor ( `new ClientCheckoutOptions() { ... }` >> `new ClientCheckoutOptions { ... }`)

---

**UPDATE**: The most concise version I can think of:

```cs
private static readonly ImmutableArray<PaymentMethod> checkoutGroup = new []
{
   PaymentMethod.PayPalDirect,
   PaymentMethod.Braintree,
   PaymentMethod.BankTransfer,
   PaymentMethod.AdyenDropIn
}.ToImmutableArray();

public static PaymentOptions GetPaymentOptions_NonGBCulture(TestConfigurationCDO testConfiguration, int siteId)
    => new ClientCheckoutOptions
    {
        paymentMethod = SitePaymentRepository
          .GetSitePaymentInfoBySiteId(testConfiguration, siteId)
          .Select(po => po.PaymentType)
          .First(checkoutGroup.Contains)
    };
```

Comment: thank you @petercsala

Comment: This seems to be a `How to` question and that would make it off-topic and not answerable.

Comment: @pacmaninbw Yeah I know. It was such a low hanging fruit I could not resist, sorry.